# Status of Post url is "Submitted & Indexed" in GSC but url is not visible in google search manually

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Webmasters Stack Exchange post: [Status is "Submitted & Indexed" in GSC but url is not visible in google search manually](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/status-is-submitted-indexed-in-gsc-but-url-is-not-visible-in-google-search-m)

Are we blindly redirecting all the indexing related questions to one questions??

Devil is in the details, please read the question before doing something arbitrary.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) is one of our "catch-all" questions.  It was created because we get tons of very similar questions about why a site isn't indexed.  Even though the questions might be slightly different, they all have very similar answers.  For the meta thread about the creation of that catch-all question see [New Catch-All: Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/935/new-catch-all-why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

I apologize for not commenting to explain the situation when I marked your question as a duplicate.  I have since added explanatory comments.

Your question could also have been closed with the off-topic reason:

> Questions that are **specific to one website** are discouraged because they are unlikely to help future visitors. Examples include individual website reviews for SEO purposes and general website troubleshooting. See the [How to Ask](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help improving this question.

Because we are building a repository of knowledge, we require that questions be written such that they can apply to many sites.    Your question has very specific details about your site (number of articles, age of site, etc) that are only going to apply to your site at the current time.